# Using Auth0 Universal Login WITHOUT SSO

Tags: auth0

I'm trying to set up a single page Angular 2+ app with Auth0 and Universal Login *without* single sign-on. I'm following [this guide](https://auth0.com/docs/hosted-pages/login). It says:

> 1. Enable SSO for the application in the Dashboard (Go to the
>      Application's Settings, then scroll down to the Use Auth0 instead of
>      the IdP to do Single Sign On setting and toggle it on.

That's pretty clear, but for some reason the option is already enabled, and the switch/control is not clickable. I am unable to disable the option, and I can't see why.

[image]

How can I disable SSO for an Auth0 application?

——————————————————————————————

**Update:** Here's the broader issue for clarification: I just want a hosted (on auth0.com) login, but I do not want to use a single sign-on. That is, I do not want my users to be presented with a screen/modal that asks them to approve my application’s use of their email address and profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work at Auth0.  I think you are confusing two things.  The screen asking your users to consent to an application is not the same thing as SSO.  This consent screen is displayed when you are trying to issue an `access_token` for a user on a 3rd party application.  This also displays it self when you are running it locally on localhost.

The toggle you see is enabled for all clients now.  That controls whether or not the user looks at the auth0 session allowing SSO (again not consent).  Auth0 will always create an SSO cookie for each user when logging in.  You can force your users to login with prompt=login (no sso) and in a rule you could prevent SSO requests doing something like this:

```
if (context.request.query.prompt === 'none` && 
/* other criteria if not a global rule */) {
  return callback(new UnauthorizedError('This application does not support SSO.");
}
```

Comment: I'm getting it now. Thank you.